# How to parse out string elements into objects in JS?

Tags: javascript

I need to parse the following string:

```
"Apple-sweet#tangy@Bannana@Orange-citrusy@Pear-crispy#green/yellow"
```

Each item except for the first that starts with "@" is the key, "-" denotes the start of subitems for that key. "#" separates each subitem with that same key.

Into an object similar to this:

```
{
"Apple": ["sweet", "tangy"],
"Bannana":[],
"Orange": ["citrusy"],
"Pear": ["crispy", "green/yellow"]
}
```

What is the best way to parse this?

Comment: I'd recommend the use of a parser generator such as http://pegjs.majda.cz/online

Comment: @Zzirconium How can that parser generator be applied to this problem?

Comment: I added an answer with my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a lot of string manipulation functions

```
var inputString = "Apple-sweet#tangy@Bannana@Orange-citrusy@Pear-crispy#green/yellow";
var keyValues = inputString.split("@");
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < keyValues.length; ++i) {
    var index = keyValues[i].indexOf("-");
    if (index == -1) {
        obj[keyValues[i]] = [];
    } else {
        var key = keyValues[i].substring(0, index);
        var values = keyValues[i].substring(index + 1).split("#");
        obj[key] = values;
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wR9EZ/)

Answer (score 5):

You need to split the string by the guard symbols several times:

```
var str = 'Apple-sweet#tangy@Bannana@Orange-citrusy@Pear-crispy#green/yellow';
var result = {};

str.split('@').forEach(function(item){
  var split = item.split('-'); 
  result[split[0]] = split[1] && split[1].split('#') || [];
});

console.dir(result);
```

First you split by `@` to get each item from the object as a separate array value. Then you split each of the items in that array by `-` to get the key and the values. After that you need to make sure the values exist and if they do, split them by `#` to get an array of them.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/avuGagu/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

You may try this ([**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7H7wq/1/))

```
var str = "Apple-sweet#tangy@Bannana@Orange#citrusy@Pear#crispy#green/yellow";
var arr = str.split('@'), i = 0, l= arr.length, obj = {} ;
for(; i< l; i++){
    var a = arr[i].split(/-|#/);
    obj[a[0]] = a.splice(1);
}
console.log(obj);
```

Also, you can use (to make your keys `lowercase`, so you can use `apple` instead of `Apple`)

```
obj[a[0].toLowerCase()] = a.splice(1);
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7H7wq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I tried to implement your "grammar" within PEG.js

Go there http://pegjs.majda.cz/online and paste the following grammar on the grammar part (1).

```
start
  = fruits

fruits
  = ft:fruit "@" fts:fruits  {fts[ft[0]] = ft[1]; return fts;}
  / ft:fruit {var fruits = {}; fruits[ft[0]] = ft[1]; return fruits;}

fruit
  = name:word "-" flavs:flavors {var ft = []; ft.push(name); ft.push(flavs); return ft;}
  / name:word {var ft = []; ft.push(name); ft.push([]); return ft;}

flavors
  = flavor:word "#" flavs:flavors {flavs.unshift(flavor); return flavs;}
  / flavor:word { var tab = []; tab.push(flavor); return tab;}

word
  = value:[a-zA-Z/]+ {return value.join("");}
```

Then put the sentence in the input section (2)

```
Apple-sweet#tangy@Bannana@Orange-citrusy@Pear-crispy#green/yellow
```

And here comes the result :

```
{
   "Pear": [
      "crispy",
      "green/yellow"
   ],
   "Orange": [
      "citrusy"
   ],
   "Bannana": [],
   "Apple": [
      "sweet",
      "tangy"
   ]
}
```

Then embed the resulting javascript parser into a file you won't have to bother about the lexical/syntaxic analysis job. Better maintenability to come only working at semantic level IMHO :)

Quite powerful API, although in this particular case it is a bit overkill ;)